# OSMnx - problems with example file

Tags: python, data-visualization, shapefile, osmnx

I'm really new to Python and to OSMnx as well. I'm trying to figure out how this package works, my ultimate goal would be to be able to create shapefiles from a list of streets and I hope this package can get me closer to this.

Unfortunately, I've already had problems with running the example code for getting street network for a single city.

This is how the example code starts:

```
import osmnx as ox
%matplotlib inline
ox.config(log_file=False, log_console=True, use_cache=True)
```

and then this is I'd like to run:

```
# get walking network from Szigethalom
G = ox.graph_from_place('Szigethalom, Hungary', network_type = 'walk')
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G)
```

and the error message is this:

[image: Error message - part 1]

[image: Error message - part 2]

I use the win7 and jupyter framework.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: It works for me (in IPython, not a Notebook). What python version are you using? I had some troubles with 3.7, but it works with 3.6.3

Comment: According to [this issue](https://github.com/jswhit/pyproj/issues/134), it might also be a problem of the anaconda install. Can you try it in a virtualenv? You can see how to create one [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

Comment: @RunOrVeith
I use Python 3.7. I just reinstalled anaconda the other day. I'll try the virtualenv.

Comment: Can you try the following in the terminal (assuming problem.py contains the 4 lines of python above, without the matplotlib inline):
`python3 -m venv test`
`source test/bin/activate`
`pip install osmnx`
`python problem.py` and see if that works? You might also have to `sudo apt install python3-rtree` for osmnx to work

Comment: @RunOrVeith

Thanks for your suggestion, however it doesn't seem to work. I run into other problems in the new virtual environment (created by this way: [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/environment-management-with-conda-python-2-3-b9961a8a5097)): installing of the osmnx doesn't work at all with pip (and besides installing rtree nothing really works with pip), so I'm trying to install geopandas (as a dependency of osmnx) and osmnx with conda. 

What is the difference between pip and sudo apt install?  Is sudo apt install for windows?

Comment: Oh my bad I didn't realize you are on Windows. The sudo apt stuff is for linux. I'm not really familiar with Windows, so I can't help you there. But I am pretty sure there is a problem with osmnx in conda, so you might not be able to use it (easily). Look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) in the windows section on how to create a virtual environment without anaconda. This however requires an installation of python, which you might not have outside of anacoda. I can't really help you with it on Windows, sorry

Comment: You helped me a lot!
I created an environment using "conda" and managed to use it in jupyter notebook as well. I installed geopandas, rtree and osmnx using "conda -c install..." in this environment. Before I created it, I had to reinstall anaconda and now I use python 3.6. And it's working. You gave me the kickstart with your suggestion and so I learnt a lot! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue appears to be that pyproj is not installed properly. I see you've answered your question, but there's a somewhat simpler answer. If you have installation problems such as this, you can follow the [OSMnx instructions](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#installation) that state:

> If you have any trouble with the installation, try installing OSMnx in a new, clean virtual environment using conda and conda-forge:

```
conda create --override-channels -c conda-forge -n OSMNX python=3
osmnx source activate OSMNX
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your advice! with a lot of trial and error, this clean, new virtual environment was the way I could use your package. unfortunately I didn't read this part of OSMnx instructions, before I asked here, but now, everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

With some help of RunOrVeith I figured out a way which is working now.

1. I use Python 3.6 instead of 3.7.
2. I created a virtual environment following [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/environment-management-with-conda-python-2-3-b9961a8a5097) site, using *conda*.
3. I installed in the newly created environment **geopandas**, **rtree** and **osmnx**, following [this](https://geoffboeing.com/2016/11/osmnx-python-street-networks/) blog article, using *conda install -c conda-forge nameofpackage*
4. I run the code above in my question.